# React How to fire onClick each from map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some lists which are mapped and I'd like to fire onClick when I click an element(which is one of objects from the array).

Let's say there are 3 lists and when I click one of them, I'd like to change "the element that i clicked"'s class to 'open' from 'close'.

```
state= {
    open: false
}

handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
        open: !this.state.open
    })
}

Array.map((list, index) => {
    <div key={index} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <p className={this.state.open? 'open' : 'close'}>{list.title}</p>
    </div>
})
```

.

```
Array = [{
    title: 'a',
    link: '/service/wallet'
},{
    title: 'b',
    link: '/service/home'
}]
```

I have a value of `this.props.location.pathname` and I think I can compare this to `Array[i].link`.

something like this?

```
if(this.props.location.pathname === Array[0].link){

}
```

However, I don't know how to complete the code for this issue. please tell if my idea is right and some hints.

Comment: `onClick={() => this.handleClick(list)}` - pass whatever you want to `handleClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to keep the "is it clicked?" information in `this.state`. Because it's a *list* of things you need to keep track of you can't store the state in a single variable, you'll need a map of them.

```
state= {
    open: {}
}

handleClick = (link) => {
    let linkOpenState = false;
    if (this.state.open.hasOwnProperty(link)) {
        linkOpenState = this.state.open[link];
    }

    this.setState({ open: { [link]: linkOpenState } })
}

Array.map((list, index) => {
    <div key={index} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, list.link)}>
        <p className={this.state.open[list.link]? 'open' : 'close'}>{list.title}</p>
    </div>
})
```

You need to get used to thinking "the React way". State needs to be kept in component state (or if complexity becomes a problem then look at Redux). You don't *imperatively* manipulate the DOM and you don't "ask" the DOM for information, you *tell* it how it should look based on the state.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this code [mapping data with react elements](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7jyv980l4)

To solve this problem, you can have a state which tracks the interaction for a group of elements, in your case it is list of elements.
here you can use a map in a state variable and have {key,value} pair associated with each element to track it.
Hope this helps.
Thanks.