# Reactjs handleclick binding in a nested map not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am writing a simple blog component in React. The component get the post from a second file and renders the content and the hashtags with  `map`  (in particular two nested `map`). I was trying to create a part in which the hashtag are highlighted when clicked, and hence I was following the snippet of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53262169/react-how-to-fire-onclick-each-from-map-function). The fact is that it is not working and in particular what it is not working is the binding through `bind` (checked with `console.log` output)

```
class Blog extends React.Component {
state= {
    open: {}
}

handleClick = (k) => {
    let linkOpenState = true;
    if (this.state.open.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        linkOpenState = !this.state.open[k];
    }
    this.setState({ open: { [k]: linkOpenState } })
}

render(){
return(
posts.map(i=>(
  <div class="box">
    <article class="media">
      <div class="media-content">
        <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">{i.title}</h1>
          <p>
            {i.content}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="tags">
         {i.hash.map(k=>(<span id={k} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,k)} class={this.state.open[k]? "tag is-primary" : "tag"} >{k}</span>))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>))
)
}
}
export default Blog
```

Anyone has an idea of what is wrong there? Is it the nested map a problem for the bind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React expects a single element as a return. You can solve this by wrapping the return in a fragment as `<React.Fragment>` or `<>`.
Also, you don't need to bind an arrow function(`handleClick` when mapping `i.hash`).

```
render(){
 return(
  <>
  posts.map(i=>(
  <div class="box">
    <article class="media">
      <div class="media-content">
        <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">{i.title}</h1>
          <p>
            {i.content}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="tags">
          {i.hash.map(k=>(<span key={k} id={k} onClick={() => this.handleClick(k)} class={this.state.open[k]? "tag is-primary" : "tag"} >{k}</span>))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>))
</>)}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. The value seem passed correctly to the HandleClick now but the problem seems to be now with the if in the handleclick that is never realized correctly (it seems the HasOwnProperty is not realized).

Comment: @albiremo Didn't get it. Can you comment the error?

Comment: There is no error. Simply I do not obtain the desired behaviour. Let's say that I add a bunch of  `console.log` to check if this `handleClick` works
```
handleClick = (k) => {
    let linkOpenState = false;
    if (this.state.open.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        linkOpenState = this.state.open[k];
    }
    this.setState({ open: { [k]: linkOpenState } })
console.log(k)
console.log(linkOpenState)
console.log(this.state)
}
```
I see that when I click on the hashtag, the `linkOpenState` return always false.

Comment: So it seems that the code never enter in the `if`

Comment: @albiremo Yes. Does your state `open` have a property with the keys passes? I could see that you are initializing it as an empty object.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed it, the problem was in the `linkOpenState` part. I fix it in the question. thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bind the arrow function.
Also, you need to pass unique key to elements when used inside map, you can use index as a key but if you are mutating the array then use some id or hash or anything which will be unique.

```
class Blog extends React.Component {
state= {
    open: {}
}

handleClick = (k) => {
    let linkOpenState = false;
    if (this.state.open.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        linkOpenState = this.state.open[k];
    }
    this.setState({ open: { [k]: linkOpenState } })
}

render(){
return(
posts.map((i, index)=>(
  <div class="box" key={i.id || index}>
    <article class="media">
      <div class="media-content">
        <div class="content">
        <h1 class="title">{i.title}</h1>
          <p>
            {i.content}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="tags">
         {i.hash.map(k=>(<span key={k} id={k} onClick={() => this.handleClick(k)} class={this.state.open[k]? "tag is-primary" : "tag"} >{k}</span>))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>))
)
}
}
export default Blog
```